# How to track post views or likes on high traffic WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics-api

I'm developing a theme for a high traffic WordPress site - tens of thousands of visitors a day.

**Current working feature**:
I have a working feature that displays post views for the top performing posts. I'm using the Google Analytics API to retrieve the post views for the top X posts. There's a cron job that runs once a week to retrieve the previous week's stats.

With the changes coming to Google Analytics, and the deprecation of the UA platform and its API, I want to consider alternative solutions.

**Desired feature**:
I'd like to ditch GA and be able to display daily stats. I'm skeptical of the plugins available that are updating the post metadata on each page view. I suspect with our traffic, writing to the SQL database on every page view would be problematic.

What methods are available to me to efficiently track page views? I'd need to track daily page views for 10K+ posts.

Comment: I did a page tracker not so long ago, how much detail do you want to track, if it's just daily count per page, I'd suggest a new table [columns: id:page_id:datestamp:counter] Date:set to Ymd ie:20220427 setting this to be unique key as well, then on your front end set up an async ajax call that calls a function which records `INSERT xxxx ON DUPLICATE KEY ****` etc; very light weight and quick

Comment: @BarrieDawson - would there be any performance issues if we were to have more than 10k visitors a day? When I updated an ACF value in this Ajax way, WP Engine notified us that it was causing problems.

Comment: My primary server has 10k visitors an hour, true I'm runnning a mySql Galera cluster but with the amount of SQL that WP runs on INIT this should be a drop in the ocean. ACF has a lot more triggers so that possibly adds to your overrhead on that one. You could look into a noSql option like REDIS and on a new day transpose that data from REDIS to mySql, but it does have to account for REDIS TTL and volatility